# Вывод чисел по возрастанию. Задача должна быть сделана только с уловным оператором (без циклов)

Tags: c, условия

Напишите программу, которая запрашивает четыре числа и выводит их в порядке возрастания.

Ограничения: −10000 ≤ a,b,c,d ≤ 10000, где a,b,c,d - целые числа.

Ввод

В первой строке находятся четыре целых числа.

Вывод

Вывести числа в порядке возрастания.

**Задача должна быть сделана только используя условный оператор (никаких циклов)**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{int a,b,c,d;
scanf("%d%d%d%d",&a,&b,&c,&d);
if (a < b && a < c && a <d){
    if (b < c && b <d){
        if (c < d){
            printf("%d %d %d %d",a,b,c,d);
        }
        else{
            printf("%d %d %d %d",a,b,d,c);
        }
    }
    else if(c < b && c < d){
        if (b < d){
            printf("%d %d %d %d",a,c,b,d);
        }
        else{
            printf("%d %d %d %d",a,c,d,b);
        }
    }
    else{
        if (c < b){
            printf("%d %d %d %d",a,d,c,b);
        }
        else{
            printf("%d %d %d %d",a,d,b,c);
        }
    }
}
else if(b < a && b < c && b <d){
    if (a < c && a <d){
        if (c < d){
            printf("%d %d %d %d",b,a,c,d);
        }
        else{
            printf("%d %d %d %d",b,a,d,c);
        }
    }
    else if(c < a && c < d){
        if (a < d){
            printf("%d %d %d %d",b,c,a,d);
        }
        else{
            printf("%d %d %d %d",b,c,d,a);
        }
    }
    else{
        if (c < a){
            printf("%d %d %d %d",b,d,c,a);
        }
        else{
            printf("%d %d %d %d",b,d,a,c);
        }
    }
}
else if (c <a && c < b && c < d){
    if (a < b && a <d){
        if (b < d){
            printf("%d %d %d %d",c,a,b,d);
        }
        else{
            printf("%d %d %d %d",c,a,d,b);
        }
    }
    else if(b < a && b < d){
        if (a < d){
            printf("%d %d %d %d",c,b,a,d);
        }
        else{
            printf("%d %d %d %d",c,b,d,a);
        }
    }
    else{
        if (a < b){
            printf("%d %d %d %d",c,d,a,b);
        }
        else{
            printf("%d %d %d %d",c,d,b,a);
        }
    }
}
else{
    if (a < c && a <b){
        if (c < b){
            printf("%d %d %d %d",d,a,c,b);
        }
        else{
            printf("%d %d %d %d",d,a,b,c);
        }
    }
    else if(c < b && c < a){
        if (b < a){
            printf("%d %d %d %d",d,c,b,a);
        }
        else{
            printf("%d %d %d %d",d,c,a,b);
        }
    }
    else{
        if (a < c){
            printf("%d %d %d %d",d,b,a,c);
        }
        else{
            printf("%d %d %d %d",d,b,c,a);
        }
    }    
}

    return 0;
}
```

Код не рабочий.

Comment: А вопрос-то в чем?

Comment: код нерабочий. Почему-то проверка его валит

Comment: ну так посмотри какие числа в проверке и вручную пройдись с этими числами по коду. Что ты ожидаешь-то тут? Что кто-то будет вчитываться в буквы и искать ошибку, а то и просто опечатку?

Comment: Ну так потестируйте разные варианты...

Comment: Имхо для 4 чисел проще написать какую-нибудь сортировку

Comment: Неправильно обрабатывается случай с равными друг другу числами. Например, `1 1 1 3` выведет `3 1 1 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если все значения различные, ошибки нет. Если несколько значений совпадают, начинаются проблемы. Например `1 1 1 2` -> `2 1 1 1`. Думаю что починить можно заменив все сравнения на нестрогие.

Но есть решение проще и короче.

У четырёх значений *4!* перестановок. *2<sup>4</sup> < 4! ≤ 2<sup>5</sup>*. То есть пяти сравнений достаточно чтобы упорядочить их, а четырёх мало.

Пять сравнений:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ORDER(a, b)     \
    do {                \
        if (a > b) {    \
            int t = a;  \
            a = b;      \
            b = t;      \
        }               \
    } while (0)

int main() {
    int a, b, c, d;
    scanf("%d%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
    ORDER(a, b);
    ORDER(c, d);
    ORDER(a, c); /* в а минимальное значение */
    ORDER(b, d); /* в d максимальное значение */
    ORDER(b, c);
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n", a, b, c, d);
}
```

**P.S.** `do {...} while (0)` внутри макроса - это не цикл, а [способ оформлять многострочные макросы в C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136).

Comment: А зачем `do {...} while(0)`, когда можно просто `{...}`?

Comment: @LShadow77, чтобы заставить  пользователя макроса писать `;` после вызова. [Why use apparently meaningless do-while and if-else statements in macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136)

Answer (score 3):

Вроде бы теоретически должно 5 сравнений хватать (16 < 4!=24 < 32), но мне лень думать :)

```
#define  SWAP(a,b) { int t = a; a = b; b = t; }
int main()
{
    int a,b,c,d;
    scanf("%d%d%d%d",&a,&b,&c,&d);
    if (a > b) SWAP(a,b);
    if (c > d) SWAP(c,d);
    if (b > c) SWAP(b,c);
    if (a > b) SWAP(a,b);
    if (c > d) SWAP(c,d);
    if (b > c) SWAP(b,c);
    printf("%d %d %d %d",a,b,c,d);
}
```